# jQuery variables mistakes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I made a mistake here because it isn't working probably. Maybe someone can help me

Here's my jQuery code (I think the rest is not important):

$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggled = false;

```
$(".arrow").click(function () {
    if (toggled === false) {
        $(".nav").animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
        $(".arrow").animate({
            left: "280px"
        });
        toggled = true;
    } else {
        $(".nav").animate({
            left: "-280px;"
        });
        $(".arrow").animate({
            left: "0px;"
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you

EDIT: Found my mistake

```
$(".nav").animate({
            left: "-280px;"
        });
```

The ";" is very wrong in the animation bracket :)

Comment: In `else` part, no `toggled = false;` so it won't be able to switch between 2 state?

Comment: @fuyushimoya forgot that.. But it still isn't animating back in..

Comment: I think There should be 2 '==' instead of 3.'===' verifies if these are of the same type and value while'==' checks the value

Answer (score 1):

You need one more closing braces for document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var toggled = false;
    $(".arrow").click(function () {
        if (toggled === false) {
            $(".nav").animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
            $(".arrow").animate({
                left: "280px"
            });
            toggled = true;
        } else {
            $(".nav").animate({
                left: "-280px;"
            });
            $(".arrow").animate({
                left: "0px;"
            });
        }
    });
}); // you missed this
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set `toggled` in the `else` condition:

```
var toggled = false;

$(".arrow").click(function () {
    if (toggled === false) {
        $(".nav").animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
        $(".arrow").animate({
            left: "280px"
        });
        toggled = true;
    } else {
        $(".nav").animate({
            left: "-280px;"
        });
        $(".arrow").animate({
            left: "0px;"
        });
        toggled = false;
    }
});
```